# How to determine whether an iOS promo code has been redeemed?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I've been googling to find out if there's a way to determine if one of my promo codes has been redeemed.

I've found solutions say use the redeem link in the iTunes mac app, enter the promo code (it will say if it's been redeemed) then when it asks for the password, click cancel.

However this no longer works, clicking redeem asking you for you user name and password as soon as you click the link.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the only way to check if a promo code has been redeemed is [Tokens](http://usetokens.com).
It is a Mac application (FREE for one app, $29 for more) which allows you to generate, share and track them.

This is possible because instead of sharing the promo code itself, you will share a tokn.co URL containing your code. When a user redeem it, you can see "Redeemed" below the name of the person you shared the code with.

Unfortunately, I don't know if it also works with code generated using iTunes Connect but you can find more information on its website!

Comment: Thanks and yes I intended to use this, but I'd like to determine codes I've already sent out have been used.

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE:** Note that it seems this method unfortunately **no longer works**. Entering an iOS code in the Mac app store successfully redeems it now.

---

For an iOS app, enter the code into the *Mac app store* redeem box (on front page, look under **Quick Links** - there's a **Redeem** link).

- If the code has been used, it'll say "This code has already been redeemed"
- If the code is available, it'll say "This code must be redeemed in iTunes"

This is *after* logging in, and is safe (won't ever accidentally redeem) and fast!

*(Inspired by Tom's solution which seemed close but the wrong way round?!)*

Comment: The opposite also works: Trying Mac App Store codes in iTunes!

Comment: Careful! It seems to me that this works only *before* your app is officially released. Today I tried an iTunes code for a live app in the Mac App store and unfortunately my precious, precious code was still redeemed :(

Comment: It just redeemed my code for my not live app.  Guess this no longer works?

Answer (score 0):

Try redeeming it on an iPhone, will either say 'redeemed' or 'use the app store'.